# How to work with nested loop, looping through array elements?

Tags: python, fasta

Coming from R background, I wanted to try nested for-loop in python. I am having trouble looping through each iteration of `types` in my code below. My code works for `types[0]`, but not for successive iterations. How do I solve this?

```
import sys
import os
myfasta = sys.argv[1]
fasta = open(myfasta)
types = ['CDS', 'tRNA', 'rRNA']

for type in range(len(types)):
    print('My type index is: ' + str(type))
    flag = False
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>') and types[type] in line:
            flag = True
        elif line.startswith('>'):
          flag = False
        if flag:
            print(line.strip())
```

`myfasta`

```
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
GGGGTTTTTTT
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>5_rRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>6_tRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
```

Expected result:

```
My type index is: 0
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
GGGGTTTTTTT
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
My type index is: 1
>5_rRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
My type index is: 2
>6_tRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
```

Comment: I dont trust that output, where is your print("My type index is:")??? Pls edit it

Comment: This seems like it'd be easily solvable by using a debugger to step through your code line-by-line. If you aren't doing that already, I'd recommend learning how to do that before anything else, since it's such an essential tool for doing any kind of programming. I'd recommend PyCharm because it's an IDE with a GUI, and has a very good built-in debugging feature.

Comment: Also, just a general style comment, it's usually best not to use reserved keywords as variable names (in your case, `type`). [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) recommends appending an underscore or using a synonym (e.g. `kind` or `type_`).

Comment: For starters, don't loop over a range, you don't actually need the elements, just the item inside `types`. Also, you will only ever loop once over an opened file, either use `.seek` or re-open the file in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't load your file once and iterate over it as often as you want.

`open()` returns an iterator, which can only be consumed once.

Adapt your code to iterate over your file multiple times

```
import sys
import os
myfasta = sys.argv[1]
types = ['CDS', 'tRNA', 'rRNA']

for type in range(len(types)):
    print('My type index is: ' + str(type))
    flag = False
    fasta = open(myfasta)
    for line in fasta:
        if line.startswith('>') and types[type] in line:
            flag = True
        elif line.startswith('>'):
          flag = False
        if flag:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Wouldn't reading the same file multiple times makes it memory intensive?

Comment: @MAPK no, it would make it *memory efficient* since it is reading it line by line, but it is I/O intensive. You could materialize all the lines into a list, i.e. `with open(myfasta) as f: data = list(f)` and then loop over `data` instead.

Comment: Its debatable whether you would want to store it into a list or read it multiple times. I would argue that it depends on the size of the file vs the number of times you read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import sys
import os

myfasta = sys.argv[1]
with open(myfasta) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
types = ['CDS', 'tRNA', 'rRNA']

for type_index, type in enumerate(types):
    print('My type index is:', type_index)
    flag = False
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('>') and type in line:
            flag = True
        elif line.startswith('>'):
            flag = False
        if flag:
            print(line.strip())
```

**Output**

```
My type index is: 0
>1_CDS
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
AAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCC
GGGGTTTTTTT
>2_CDS
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
>3_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
>4_CDS
TTTGGGAATTAAACCCT
My type index is: 1
>6_tRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
My type index is: 2
>5_rRNA
TTAAAAATTTCTGGGCCCCGGGAAAAAA
```

Comment: Thanks. Could please explain this bit: `with open(myfasta) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()`

Comment: The file is opened and all the lines of the file are stored in the variable `lines`. When the `with` context manager is exited, the file is closed automatically

Comment: with `readlines` it is possible to store all lines of a file in a list in one statement. the list can then be iterated over later